# Using a timestamp function in a GROUP BY

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working with a large transaction data set and would like to group a count of individual customer transactions by month. I am unable to use the timestamp function in the `GROUP BY` and return the following error:

> BAD_QUERY (expression STRFTIME_UTC_USEC([DATESTART], '%b') in GROUP BY is invalid)

Is there a simple workaround to achieve this or should I build a calendar table (which may be the simplest option)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to use an alias:

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATESTART, '%b') as month, COUNT(TRANSACTION)
FROM datasetId.tableId
GROUP BY month
```

Answer (score 4):

@Charles is correct but as an aside you can also group by column number.

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATESTART, '%b') as month, COUNT(TRANSACTION) as count
FROM [datasetId.tableId]
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```