# display data month wise in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

```
select date_add('2015-01-15',(7-dayofweek('2015-01-15')),"day"),
        date_add('2015-01-15',(14-dayofweek('2015-01-15')),"day")
```

output of this query is

```
Row f0_ f1_  
1   2015-01-17 00:00:00 UTC 2015-01-24 00:00:00 UTC
```

but i want to display the data as

```
sno    date                      sum
1  2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC        20(first month sum)
2 2015-02-01 00:00:00 UTC         30 (second month sum)
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I got answer for above requirement.But I want print the month in words like 01 as jan

Comment: Please any one tell me how to display 01-2014 as jan 2014 in single column

Comment: on this page you will find Date and Time functions https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference

Answer (score 2):

The STRFTIME_UTC_USEC has rich formatting of dates, the code for month names is %b, i.e.

```
select strftime_utc_usec(date_add('2015-01-15',
          (7-dayofweek('2015-01-15')),"day"), "%Y-%b-%e"),
       strftime_utc_usec(date_add('2015-01-15',
          (14-dayofweek('2015-01-15')),"day"), "%Y-%b-%e")
```

results in

```
Row f0_         f1_  
1   2015-Jan-17 2015-Jan-24
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum, if you want to display the data from each month in multiple rows, you can use GROUP BY. There's an example here: [Using a timestamp function in a GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262361/using-a-timestamp-function-in-a-group-by).